# Change a time format from 00:00:00 into seconds in Sql

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, webforms

Within my ASP.Net application I have an Sql database. One of the columns in a table is called   productDelivered which uses the data type time(7); however, i would like to convert the time to seconds and keep it. I have around 50-60 records.

Is there a way to change these times to seconds? I dont mind creating a new column in the table for productDeliveredSeconds but I thought maybe a stored procedure or a view might do it?

Comment: You tagged both mysql and sql-server. Please clarify.

Comment: @John Dewey I am using Sql within Visual Studio and was unsure which category it was covered under. I have now removed sql-server.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a [computed column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186241.aspx) to your table that uses [datediff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) to calculate the number of seconds.

```
alter table YourTable add productDeliveredSeconds as datediff(second, 0, productDelivered)
```

Or you can use `datediff` in a query.

```
select datediff(second, 0, productDelivered) as productDeliveredSeconds 
from YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

`TIME_TO_SEC(time)` returns the time argument, converted to seconds.

```
mysql> SELECT TIME_TO_SEC('22:23:00');
        -> 80580
mysql> SELECT TIME_TO_SEC('00:39:38');
        -> 2378
```

Comment: I'm abit lost with your answer, where are the results collected from and outputted to?